# Getting max record by delaying in the received event

Tags: c++

I have tool which will send record .This tool can select multiple record at time but it
send event for each record.

I want to get Max record by put dealy when i receive a RecordChangedEvent in my code as below:

Its working good but for every event delayed occurred not sure why.

```
RecordChangedEvent(void)
{
        static bool lock=false;
        bool updateNewRecord =false;

        /*delaying for 20sec when frist event received so that max record can be received */
        if(!lock)  
        {
                lock=true;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
                updateNewRecord=true;  
        }
        if(updateNewRecord)
        {


                      //ading after 20 sec dealy changed.list will have all the updated received record within 20 sec                
                        AddedRecord(changed.list);       

                        lock=false;

        }


}
```

Comment: @Greenonline While I liked your edits of the introductory text, fixing the style issues should be left to a review in an answer.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify if this code already does what you intend it to do. If not, it would be off-topic here, since we don't write code for you, we generally just improve what you already have. Take the [tour] and have a look at our [help].

Comment: @Graipher - thanks for the explanation. Understood. My original intention was, merely, to aid readability, as I assumed that the indentation had, somehow, got messed up in the copy-paste process. I can see now that I should have *really* left it as it was.

Comment: @Greenonline Indentation is always a difficult thing. If there is excessive overall indentation the consensus seems to be that you can strip it, but don't have to. But fixing the whitespace around operators would definitely be something to leave to an actual answer. Have a look at [this relevant meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6124/98493).

Answer (score 2):

After cleaning up the code, for the purposes of readability:

- Indentation
- Spaces around operators
- Consistent use of comments

It now looks like this:

```
RecordChangedEvent(void)
{
    static bool lock = false;
    bool updateNewRecord = false;

    // delaying for 20 sec when first event received so that max record can be received
    if(!lock)  
    {
        lock = true;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
        updateNewRecord = true;  
    }
    if(updateNewRecord)
    {
        // adding after 20 sec delay changed.list will have all the updated received records within 20 seconds                
        AddedRecord(changed.list);       
        lock = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, this is basically just a very roundabout way of writing:

```
RecordChangedEvent(void)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));
    AddedRecord(changed.list);
}
```

If you intend for this to be used in multiple threads, with `lock` ensuring that only one thread enters the `if (!lock)` section at a time, then you'll need to change it to an `std::atomic<bool>`, or something on that order. As it stands right now, if it's accessed from more than one thread, you have a race condition (and therefore, undefined behavior).

Rather than sleeping a thread to delay the processing, I'd probably do something like putting each record into a queue, along with a time it should be processed. One thread will deal with incoming records, add the processing time, and put them into the queue. Another thread will sleep until the time to process the next record, retrieve it from the queue, process it, and repeat.

This makes it relatively easy to (for example) have multiple threads receiving records and/or multiple threads processing records. It also means that if (for example) your intent was to look through all the records received in the last 20 seconds, and insert only the largest among them, you have all the records and their arrival times in a queue, so it's trivial to filter them all (or, depending on the situation, you may want to use a priority queue so the next record you want will be immediately at the head of the queue).